# how to enable the zeppelin python.conda

Tags: apache-zeppelin

My linux has installed miniconda2 and set `$PATH=/root/miniconda2/bin:/root/miniconda2/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin`.

Python interpreter as follow picture.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GLLV.jpg)

Notebook error as follow picture.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiz0d.jpg)

Who can help me

Comment: Please post text content as text instead of screenshots

Comment: Interpreter error log in informative. Try to run `conda info` in the command line.

Comment: conda info command is ok